# Property of spectral norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition

The spectral norm of the matrix A is defined by

$$||A||_2=\bar{\sigma}(A)$$

where $\bar{\sigma}(A)$ is the maximum singular value of A.

Well, I can't undestand why, given two matrices A and B,

$$\bar{\sigma}(A\cdot B)\leq \bar{\sigma}(A)\cdot \bar{\sigma}(B)$$

I can't understarnd which property is involved... It is not the triangular inequality, not the omogeneity property... Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms

If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $\mathbb C^n$, then it induces a matrix norm by the following:
$$
\|A\|:= \mathrm{sup}\left\{ \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\ :\ 0\ne x\in\mathbb C^n\right\}.$$ 
These induced norms clearly satisfy $\|AB\|\le \|A\|\|B\|$ for all square matrices $A, B$.

Now the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm you defined in terms of the singular value decomposition happens to be the norm induced by the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb C^n$; see the linked Wikipedia page. In particular, the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm satisfies the property you ask for.

Comment: Ok, you got the point. As a norm, it satisfies $||AB||\leq ||A||\cdot||B||$. But I can't undestand why a matrix norm has to satisfy this property...

Comment: Not *any* norm. Only the induced ones.

Comment: How about for not necessarily square matrices?

Comment: Then you see the matrices as mappings $C^n\to C^m$ and $C^m\to C^k$. You have a norm on each of these spaces. If the norms are induced, then the product formula still holds. It is straightforward to see, same proof.